# How to make date and time update automatically in Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, datetime

It's a simple Spring MVC app.

I would like the date & time to auto-update. How do I do that? JS script to refresh every 60 seconds seems a bad idea, since I'll see the page flickering every 60s. I do not want all the contents to reload, just a timer to run smoothly and automatically. Here's a snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Try Rest call or AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really good idea to hint server with updating date at all. Implement this using JS script, i.e. something like:

```
$.timer( function() {
    var nowTime = $.now();
    // format date and insert text into selector
} , 60000);
```